# Android Studio Kotlin recyclerview with multiple views has missing data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that can have three different views base on the data with three different record types. If the data is composed of all type 1 records or both type 1 and type 2 records, then all of the data is displayed properly. But if a type 3 record is present, then no data following that type 3 record is displayed. And I am not getting any sort of error that I can find.

[image: Here is the data displayed with just type 1 and type 2 records. All records are displayed.]

[image: Here are the results of that same data when a type 3 record was added following the first type 2 record.]

Any following type 1 and type 2 records are not displayed.

Here is the code for my recyclerview adapter:

```
class ShipsAdapter (private val stateroomInfo: ArrayList<StateroomAdapterData>,
                    private val listener: OnItemClickListener):
       RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var rowType = 0

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
       rowType = when (stateroomInfo[position].adapterRecordType) {
            Constants.SHIP_ROW -> Constants.SHIP_ROW
            Constants.STATEROOM_ROW -> Constants.STATEROOM_ROW
            else -> Constants.STATEROOM_PROPERTIES_ROW
        }
        return rowType
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =
         when (rowType){
            Constants.SHIP_ROW -> {
                val view = ListShipsRecyclerItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                                                                            parent, false)
                ListShipsViewHolder(view)
            }
            Constants.STATEROOM_ROW -> {
                val view = ListStateroomsRecyclerItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                                                                                    parent, false)
                ListStateroomsViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> {
                val view = ListStateroomPropertiesRecyclerItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                                                                                parent, false)
                ListStateroomPropertiesViewHolder(view)
            }
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (rowType) {
            Constants.SHIP_ROW -> (holder as ListShipsViewHolder).bind(position)
            Constants.STATEROOM_ROW -> (holder as ListStateroomsViewHolder).bind(position)
            Constants.STATEROOM_PROPERTIES_ROW -> (holder as ListStateroomPropertiesViewHolder).bind(position)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return stateroomInfo.size
    }

    inner class ListShipsViewHolder(shipsRow: ListShipsRecyclerItemRowBinding):
                                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(shipsRow.root),
                                    View.OnClickListener {
        private val tvShip = shipsRow.tvShip
        private var ivEditShip = shipsRow.ivEditShip
        private var ivDeleteShip = shipsRow.ivDeleteShip
        private var ivStateroom = shipsRow.ivStateroom

        init {
             ivEditShip.setOnClickListener(this)
             ivDeleteShip.setOnClickListener(this)
             ivStateroom.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                if (v != null) {
                    when (v.id) {
                        R.id.ivEditShip -> listener.onItemClicked(adapterPosition, Constants.EDIT_SHIP_CLICKED)
                        R.id.ivDeleteShip -> listener.onItemClicked(adapterPosition, Constants.DELETE_SHIP_CLICKED)
                        R.id.ivStateroom -> listener.onItemClicked(adapterPosition, Constants.STATEROOM_CLICKED)
                    }
                }
        }

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val shipData = stateroomInfo[position]
            tvShip.text = shipData.ship
        }
    }

    inner class ListStateroomsViewHolder(stateroomRow: ListStateroomsRecyclerItemRowBinding):
                                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(stateroomRow.root),
                                        View.OnClickListener {
        private val tvStateroom = stateroomRow.tvStateroom
        private var ivEditStateroom = stateroomRow.ivEditStateroom
        private var ivDeleteStateroom = stateroomRow.ivDeleteStateroom

        init {
            ivEditStateroom.setOnClickListener(this)
            ivDeleteStateroom.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                if (v != null) {
                    when (v.id) {
                        R.id.ivEditStateroom -> listener.onItemClicked(adapterPosition, Constants.EDIT_STATEROOM_CLICKED)
                        R.id.ivDeleteStateroom -> listener.onItemClicked(adapterPosition, Constants.DELETE_STATEROOM_CLICKED)
                    }
                }
        }

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val stateroomData = stateroomInfo[position]
            tvStateroom.text = stateroomData.stateroom
        }
    }

    inner class ListStateroomPropertiesViewHolder(stateroomPropertiesRow: ListStateroomPropertiesRecyclerItemRowBinding):
                                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(stateroomPropertiesRow.root),
                                    View.OnClickListener {
        private val tvBedrooms = stateroomPropertiesRow.tvBedrooms
        private val tvBaths = stateroomPropertiesRow.tvBathrooms
        private val tvConnecting = stateroomPropertiesRow.tvIsConnecting
        private val ivEditStateroomProperties = stateroomPropertiesRow.ivEditStateroomProperties

        init {
            ivEditStateroomProperties.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val stateroomPropertiesData = stateroomInfo[position]
            tvBedrooms.text = stateroomPropertiesData.numBedrooms
            tvBaths.text = stateroomPropertiesData.numBaths
            tvConnecting.text = stateroomPropertiesData.connectingSuite
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                if (v != null) {
                   listener.onItemClicked(adapterPosition, Constants.EDIT_STATEROOM_PROPERTIES_CLICKED)
                }
        }
    }

    // this is required to communicate with the click listener in the Fragments
    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClicked(position: Int, clickType: Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the XML file for `ListStateroomPropertiesRecyclerItemRow` have a huge view, something with height set to `match_parent` etc? Is it actually displaying nothing else, or is the rest of the list just off the screen and needs scrolling up?

Comment: Also don't store `rowType` like that, it could be buggy if the last thing that set it doesn't happen to match the item `onBindViewHolder` is being called for. `onBindViewHolder` passes in the correct `viewType` value as a parameter (and so does `onCreateViewHolder`)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried comparing all three of the XML files to make sure that something like "match parent" did not cause the problem.  I just did not do a very good job with my comparing.  My Cardview for the type three record had a height of "match_parent" and not "wrap_content".  And that fixed the problem.